# Inter App communication in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, url-scheme, x-callback-url

Using **x-callback-url’s** , We can do app to app bidirectional communication in iOS .

One of my source app (A) can launch another my target app(B), and also provide parameters instructing the target app to return data and control back to the source app after executing an action. On this regard I have two questions.

1)Once I control back to the source app , I don't want to be put target app in background.Can we achieve this ? if it's not possible with x-calback-url please suggest alternative one, which will match above requirement.

2)Is there any apple rejection if I use x-callback-url?